# How to avoid stamping category to all messages in a thread?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-restapi

In Office 365 plugin, Our code stamps the particular mail item with a category (say "P1"). Instead of stamping only this mail item, the whole mail thread was assigned that category. All emails those are part of the mail thread which contains the stamped mail item are stamped with the category. My requirement is to assign that category only to that particular mail item. Is there any way to restrict this stamping of the whole mail thread?

Please see the attached screenshot ![stamp1_reply.png]https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBlSB.jpg

Comment: You should provide the code you are using to "stamp" the mail item with a category. Are you sure about office.js technology? are you sending EWS requests to stamp?

Comment: Yes, I am sending the EWS PATCH request to stamp.
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/itemid

with payload as {"Categories":["P1"]}
where itemID is  fetched from window.Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId
and P1 is any string

Comment: @Dheer, it appears you are making a REST call. Can you send us the code for the request to help us understand what is going?

Comment: Correction- I am using the Outlook Rest API's.

Stamping method:
Message.prototype.stampMSItem = function () {
        var self = this;

        if (!self.itemId) {
            return $.Deferred().resolve().promise();
        }

        var body = {"Categories": [MS_CATEGORY]};
        var mgr = window.app.msConnMgr;
        var resource = new mgr.O365Resource(mgr.RESOURCES.MESSAGES);
        return mgr.send(resource, resource.preparePatch(self.itemId, body));
    };

Comment: The above method and corresponding functions will fire a Rest call like below

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/AAMkADNkYTczNWQ4LWYyODMtNDI2YS04MTUzLWM0YjBhN2IxYmRjNABGAAAAAACxdaPqjbVlRLg0wpoNRunHBwBtyMiGqawmR7O9_k_QxlxgAAAAAAEJAABtyMiGqawmR7O9_k_QxlxgAAGYFDTrAAA=

Request Method: PATCH
Status Code: 200 

Request Payload:

{"Categories":["Shared with Oracle"]}

Comment: Which Outlook client client are you using? If you are using OWA, is it the "new Outlook" (look for a toggle)? If you aren't sure, it will help if you add a screenshot to the question. I tried to reproduce using the itemId returned by the add-in API, and a PATCH message request sent to the graph API. I found that after applying the category and switching to message view, only one item in the conversation had the category. But in conversation view, the way the conversation UX was presented depended on the version of OWA I was using.

Comment: I am using OWA mode. this behavior is seen in the conversation view in both old and new outlook(OWA mode). This is confusing for the user if the whole conversation is applied to that category. 

On the contrary, In the Desktop version of outlook, this issue is not seen. Even if we are in conversation view layout only one mail item is applied with that category, all other items in that thread are not marked, which seems correct.

Comment: It appears when a category is applied to a single item in the conversation, clients present the category differently. In the new OWA, if I have two items in a conversation, each with a different category, both categories are shown together on the conversation. In the older OWA, I can select items in the conversation, and see which categories are applied to each item. I don't think the REST API stamps more than one message at a time.

Comment: The case in new OWA seems misleading. Also, In old OWA, in conversation mode of the mailbox, REST API stamps only one mail-item but outlook presents it as the whole thread is stamped with that category.

Comment: Please check the screenshot of the issue mentioned above

Comment: Currently the feature you are requesting is not a part of new OWA. However, we track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user voice page https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.